# Google action app taking much time for review

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I have created one action in AOG(Action on Google). I have putted that app for review for release publicly on 10 days ago. But AOG console display still your app is in review.... So how long it will take for release AOG app ?

Comment: So how long did it take eventually?

Answer (score 1):

**From "[Publishing Your App](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#publish)":**

> - **Under Review**: When you submit a new deployment, it goes through an approval process. Reviewers test your actions and verify that you haven't violated any policies. You will receive an email once a review has been completed telling you whether your deployment was approved or not.
>
> > **Deployment status updates**
> >
> > We aim to have reviews done in a few days. However, they are currently taking about a week. We appreciate your patience as our team works to review and approve your deployments as quickly as possible.

<sup>([**Source**](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#publish))</sup>

Based on this it sounds like they're running behind so I'd suggest waiting until two weeks have passed and if the status still hasn't changed, contact Google with the form at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/).